# How could I choose true value of parameter in the simulation study

Tags: simulation, hierarchical

I have hierarchical model and I need to do simulation study. My question:
how could I chose the true value of parameter that I will use to generate data sets?
Is there rule to chose this true value of parameter?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic tool or technique that will give you "true" parameter values, i.e., unbiased estimates with zero variance.  A reasonable approach is to use [design of experiments](http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc15papers/187.pdf) to vary the parameters of your model over plausible ranges, and then build a response surface model to assess the impact of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you of your answer. Is there any book or paper that contains examples or more detail about this case to help me

Comment: I linked to a paper in the answer.  The paper has a bibliography and hyperlinks to direct you to other resources.